# Running Python code for theano: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas

Tags: python, numpy, atlas, theano

I am trying to run theano on ubuntu which requires `libatlas`.

I have already installed libatlas but I can find it in `/usr/lib/atlas-base`

I have also copied all of the files to a new folder called `/atlas`:

```
cp -a /usr/lib/atlas-base/* /usr/lib/atlas
```

But still, when I run the python code I see:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l477blas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
```

I also tried adding to environment variables but didn't work:

```
set LIBPATH = [BUILD_LIB_DIR, /usr/lib/atlas]
```

Also I tried adding the path path to ld file:

```
/usr/lib/atlas
```

or

```
/usr/lib/atlas-base
```

None of them worked and I still see the error running the Python code.

Comment: I don't think it will solve your problem, but the variable used by ``ld`` is ``LD_LIBRARY_PATH``. Or are you on Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

To change how Theano link to BLAS, you need to use Theano flags[1]. They can be set with an environment variable THEANO_FLAGS or with a configuration file.

How did you told Theano to use atlas? If you just installed the atlas packages, it won't work. You need to install the libatlas-dev pacakge as per this Theano installation instruction for Ubuntu[2]

A last point, we don't recommand atlas, especially for Ubuntu. OpenBLAS is packaged for Unbuntu and is faster. See [2] for detail on how to installed them. You will need to remove atlas before installing openblas, otherwise, there will be conflict.

[1]http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html#envvar-THEANO_FLAGS
[2]http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_ubuntu.html#install-ubuntu

Comment: I think it is trying to find blas in anaconda:
python -c 'import theano; print theano.config' | grep blas
Result:
blas.ldflags (<type 'str'>) 
    Doc:  lib[s] to include for [Fortran] level-3 blas implementation
    Value:  -L/home/#USER#/anaconda/lib -lf77blas -lcblas -latlas

How can I change this to openBlas?